# How to sort a list with data from Firebase?

Tags: list, firebase, sorting, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to sort my list in Flutter with data from Firebase. I thought it was a easy thing.. I found several codes none really working for me. I'm not really to use which code and where to put it.

```
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {

  Future getPosts() async {

    var firestore = Firestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("Gyms").getDocuments();

    return qn.documents;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPosts(),
        builder: (_, snapshot){

          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading..."),
            );
          } else {

              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index){

                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["Naam gym"]),
                    );

          });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the `orderBy()` method.

`QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("Gyms").orderBy("sort_key").getDocuments();`